# jQuery slider for iPad and iPhone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am developing a video player using html5 for iPad and iPhone device, I implemented a scrub bar for video seeking. It works fine in the normal screen, if the page is zoomed then it behaves in a different way, I need a external resource for this. Is there is any plugin for it or any other idea for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about preventing the zoom? If you design your page for a iPhone/iPad, just make it fit the screen and unzoomable.

Comment: for ipad it is considerable but in the case of iphone this will not work because without zooming it seems so small? :P